# Embedding DLLs and referencing from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF app using GMAP.Net and Extended WPF Toolkit. I reference controls from these libraries directly in my XAML. I would like to add these dlls to my project and mark them as embedded resources.

How can I continue to reference controls from XAML when I am no longer using the dll's as a reference?

EDIT: not much code to show. This works when I am using gmap as a reference.

```
xmlns:WindowsPresentation="clr-namespace:GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation;assembly=GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation"
```

Error message once I remove gmap as reference and add as embedded resource:

`Error  1   The name "GMapControl" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation;assembly=GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation".  Windows\MapWindow.xaml`

No gmap references exist in the `xmlns` intelisense/dropdown

Comment: Did you tried _anything_? Show your effort..

Comment: I have removed the dll's from my references list, and added them as embedded resources to my project. Now my project doesnt compile because my `xmlns` lookups in my XAML fail to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the dlls referenced, simply don't copy them when building your final release. Also, did you add code to the AssemblyResolve to pull in the embedded resources? My code uses gzipped assemblies.

```
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ( sender, args ) =>
        {
            try
            {
                String resourceName = String.Format( "Program.Libs.{0}.dll.gz", new AssemblyName( args.Name ).Name );
                using (var stream = new GZipStream( Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream( resourceName ), CompressionMode.Decompress ))
                using (var outstream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    CopyTo( stream, outstream );
                    return Assembly.Load( outstream.GetBuffer() );
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( e.ToString() );
                return null;                    
            }
        };

    public static long CopyTo( Stream source, Stream destination )
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[ 2048 ];
        int bytesRead;
        long totalBytes = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = source.Read( buffer, 0, buffer.Length )) > 0)
        {
            destination.Write( buffer, 0, bytesRead );
            totalBytes += bytesRead;
        }
        return totalBytes;
    }
```

Comment: What is the reasoning behind the gzip? I've seen that before

Comment: Just so that main exe is smaller. GZip can compress pretty well, roughly 50% or so.